# I'm looking for a way to work offline with Google Task

Tags: offline, google-tasks

Is it possible to work offline with Google Task and then sync it back when online? My connection is not stable over here.

Please share if you know how to.

Comment: Will Google Calendar [Offline Mode](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/view-google-calendar-offline.html) work?

Comment: @nhinkle: Not understand why you mention calendar while I'm asking about Task?

Comment: Aren't tasks part of Google Calendar? Perhaps I'm thinking of the wrong thing...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any web app that is doing that, but there are a lot of iPhone/iPad/Android apps that can be use to manage GTask offline, like:

- [GeeTasks](http://www.geetasks.com/)
- [gTasks](https://sites.google.com/site/ssi4and/home)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an iPhone you could use [Gee Tasks](http://www.geetasks.com/)